# Ansible: Use variables in standard loops

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I am trying to user variables in the below example described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

```
- name: add several users 
  user: name={{ item.name }} 
  state=present groups={{ item.groups }} 
  with_items: 
    - { name: 'testuser1', groups: 'wheel' } 
    - { name: 'testuser2', groups: 'root' }
```

This works fine, but when I try to infuse variables, it does not works as intended. I am sure, I am doing something wrong.

```
vars:
    - old:
        - ens155
        - ens160
    - new:
        - eth0
        - eth1
```

I am trying to make echo message like `ens155 is eth0` and `ens160 is eth1`, but this code shows this message - `[ens155, ens160] is [eth0, eth1]`

```
- shell: echo {{ item.old }} is {{ item.new }}
    with_items:
      - { old: '{{ old }}', new: '{{ new }}' }
```

I am happy to change the way my variables are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use [with_together](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) like below.

```
- shell: echo {{ item.0 }} is {{ item.1 }}
  with_together:
    - "{{ old }}"
    - "{{ new }}"
```

Ansible IRC Channel helped me with this.

Comment: @MattDavis Thanks, I didn't knew that. I will keep this in mind now. I can only accept this as an answer tomorrow, guess there should be a one day gap.